# OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, google-app-engine, pymysql

I am using google app engine

My settings file

```
import pymysql  # noqa: 402
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

if os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION', None):
    # Running on production App Engine, so connect to Google Cloud SQL using
    # the unix socket at /cloudsql/<your-cloudsql-connection string>
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/connectionstring',
            'USER': 'myusername',
            'PASSWORD': 'mypasswor',
            'NAME': 'mydbname',
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': '3306',
            'USER': 'username',
            'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
            'NAME': 'dbname',
        }
    }
```

Is is working fine..

Now I try to implement google authentication so used social-auth-app-django

after redirecting from google it shows the following error:

> OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'
>   ([Errno 111] Connection refused)") connect
>   (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py:629)

Comment: Check the redirect URL you're passing to Google. Are you sure it's trying to send you back to your App Engine instance and not to your local development environment? And `/cloudsql/connectionstring` isn't actually the connection string you're trying to use, right?

Comment: @kungphu google redirected to my public domain not to localhost, I think I should not reveal my connection string, it's not working only when redirected from google.

Comment: Do you only have one `settings.py` file, or do you have separate `dev` and `production` settings files?

Comment: Did you find any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the following configuration file
/etc/my.cnf

add this line: bind-address=127.0.0.1

it should fix the issue